# Regex - recognize sentence pattern

Tags: regex

I'd like to recognise a specific pattern from large text chunk, I'll be using C#.NET regex lib.

i.e.

```
1. This camera support Monochrome, Neutral, Standard, Landscape and Portrait [...More words...] settings furnish advanced, personalized color control.
Output shall be: Array ["Monocrome", "Neutral", "Standard", "Landscape", "Portrait"]
```

It should also avoid "advance" as , is followed by word.

I'm currently using expression `(([\S]+)( {0,3})?(,|and))` which returns me all words till *and*. Can you suggest me expression that covers word after *and*?

Cheers!
Nilay

Comment: Add `[^\.]*` to the end.  Example: http://regexr.com?355cf

Comment: You'd better to use split: http://www.dotnetperls.com/split

Comment: I also want to capture group of words as array, not the sentence.

Comment: Reason for regex is unstructured text, but rules are only , & (and)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the correct answer using [lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

The problem: Regex cursor will be on advance reference when comparing ahead i.e
`Monochrome, Neutral, Standard, Landscape and Portrait` consider `and` to be part of capture than the that word won't be available for next capture and therefore it will not capture Portrait. The right approach would be to use lookaround forward and backward.

`(?=( {0,1})?(,|and)))` is the correct forward lookahead, and `(?<=( {1,3}(and|or) {1,3}))` is correct backward lookbehind.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried:

```
 (([\S]+)( {0,3})?(,|and|\.))
```

http://regexr.com?355ci

Comment: How will it work in case: "1. This camera support Monochrome, Neutral, Standard, Landscape and Portrait or something other."

Comment: This won't work if sentence is like, 1. This camera support Monochrome, Neutral, Standard, Landscape and Portrait let it be more words.....

Comment: It has be forward and back reference which I'm unable to sortout.. :)

Comment: Just got solution using regex lookaround.

Answer (score 0):

Matching the list isn't too hard, but getting it into the list right is harder, and I suspect the mechanisms I'd use in perl are language dependent (I don't use microsoft products, so I won't give it to you in C#).

In perl, I'd do it something like the following.  It's not a single regex answer, but I think the code is clearer for that.

```
$string = "This camera support Monochrome, Neutral, Standard, Landscape and Portrait foo bar baz";

$re_sep = "(?: {0,3}, {0,3}| {1,3}and {1,3})";
$re_list = "\w+(?:$re_sep\w+)+";

($list) = $string =~ m/($re_list)/;
@list_elements =  split /$re_sep/, $list;
```